# How to define index based on sequence with starting and ending values

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a set of indices that defines the starts:

```
Int64Index([0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15, 20, 22], dtype='int64')
```

and ends:

```
Int64Index([2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 17, 22, 24], dtype='int64')
```

of the ranges that should be used as desirable index. In other words, I'd like to obtain an index that would include all integers from 0 to 2 (inclusive), then from 3 to 5 (inclusive), ..., from 10 to 12 (inclusive), from 15 to 17 (inclusive) and so on. The resulting index would be:

```
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, **15**, 16, 17, **20**, 21, 22, 23, 24], dtype='int64')
```

(please note the break before `15` and `20`). So the pairs of subsequent values would define the ranges and then those ranges would be joined together.

How can I obtain that?

My attempt is:

```
np.unique(np.concatenate([np.arange(start, end + 1) for start, end in zip(indices_starts, indices_ends)]))
```

But it feels like there must be more straighforward and potentially faster solution.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: I’ll second what @KGS asked, this looks like a relatively trivial task.

Comment: Updated with my current solution, but I'd like to hear for better alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

```
start = [0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15, 20, 22]
end   = [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 17, 22, 24]

# Create an empty list for your indexes
new_idx = []

# Add the new indexes
for s, e in zip(start, end):
    new_idx.extend(list(range(s,e+1)))

# Drop duplicated values
list(set(new_idx))
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your result index list is not accurate according to your description.  With the condition of the index ranges being INCLUSIVE, the resulting index list would be:

```
starts  = [0, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 15, 20, 22]
ends    = [2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 17, 22, 24]
indexes = []
for i in range(len(starts)):
    indexes.extend(list(range(starts[i], ends[i] + 1)))
print(indexes)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8, ... 20, 21, 22, 22, 23, 24]
```

With the condition of the index ranges being EXCLUSIVE:

```
...
for i in range(len(starts)):
    indexes.extend(list(range(starts[i], ends[i])))
print(indexes)
# [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 11, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Comment: list(set(indexes))